# using vba to do sumif condition to create new table

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

Thank you for welcoming me into this community. I'm very new to vba!

Essentially my goal is to categorize different services into specific service categories. I have a table with many different service types including "Adopt- Cat", "Adopt-Dog", "Cat Training" in one row and the count for that service in the next row. And I am looking for a way to grab any row that includes "Adopt*" and "*Training*" into a new table and sum the count for those rows.

Currently this is my code in VBA currently. Looking forward to your support.

Please help!

```
Sub Sum_values_if_cells_contain_adopt_and_training()
'declare a variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("catsanddogs")
'apply the formula to sum values if cells contain text

ws.Range("D1") = Application.Worksheet.SumIf(ws.Range("A1:A54"), {"adopt-*" OR "*training*"}, ws.Range("B1:B54"))

End Sub
```

When I run this code, I get an error that my code is invalid.

Very new to vba. would love to hear back.

Comment: `ws.Range("D1").Value = Application.SumProduct(Application.SumIf(ws.Range("A1:A54"), Array("adopt-*", "*training*"), ws.Range("B1:B54")))`

Comment: Will this also generate the new table?